# ayuda con datetime en mysql y netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, datetime

Estoy trabajando en un programa en el que estoy cargando los datos desde un archivos .csv y para ello lo realizo con un LOAD DATA INFILE hasta ahi todo bien, pero al momento de pasar los datos a la base de datos las horas y fechas me salen cero los mismos son DATETIME.
Aqui el codigo que uso para pasar los datos a la BD:

```
public void importarMarcaciones(String url)
 {
    try {
        url = url.replace("\\", "/");
        PreparedStatement pst;

        pst = cn.prepareStatement("LOAD DATA local INFILE '"+ url+"' INTO  
       TABLE tb_marcaciones_org FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'  lines terminated 
        by '\\r\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES ");
        pst.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guardado con Exito");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImportarArchivos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
        null, ex);
    }
 }
```